# Unset $_POST after request has been addressed

Tags: php, slim

I am implementing a login controller, as it follows :

```
public function __invoke(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response): ResponseInterface
    {
        try {
            session_start();
            $datas = [];
            $rqst = $request->getParsedBody();

            if(!isset($_SESSION["login"]) ) {
                if ((isset($rqst["email"]) && isset($rqst["pwd"]))) {
                    $loginRequest = LoginRequestFactory::from($request);


                    $loginId = $this->sessionService->connect($loginRequest);

                    if ($loginId != -1) {
                        $_SESSION["login"] = $loginId;
                    }
                  unset($_POST['email']);
                  unset($_POST['pwd']);
                }
            } else {
                if (isset($rqst["logout"])) {
                    unset($_SESSION["login"]);
                    unset($rqst["logout"]);
                }
            }
            $response = $response->withHeader('parsedBody', []);
            $response->getBody()->write($this->rend($datas));

        } catch (Exception $exception) {

            $datas = [
                'error' => $exception->getMessage(),
            ];
            $response->getBody()->write($this->rend($datas));
        }
        return $response;
    }
```

Everything works well concerning the login and the logout.

The problem is that, when the login request failed (from a login service, for example because login or password is invalid), an error is thrown from the service. This error is shown above the login form.
I want this error to disappear when I refresh the page. For that, I need to unset $_POST['email'] and $_POST['pwd'].

It doesn't work so I tried to do something like that, before returning the rendered response :

```
  $response = $response->withHeader('emaill, '');
```

Or:

```
  $reponse = $response->withoutHeader('email');
```

or:

```
  $response = $response->withoutHeader('parsedBody[\"email\"]');
```

But nothing work, so when I refresh the page, the page ask me to repost the form and the error appears again.

I don't know if the problem is a PHP problem or if it can be solved with Slim functionalities, so has somebody an idea of how to unset posted datas when I do not need them anymore ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think you're expected to use `$_POST`. Slim has already parsed the request for you.

Comment: Yes, that's why I try to modify the headers in the response

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what you're attempting to do. Removing parsed data does not prevent the user from hitting F5 and sending it again. I think you want to implement the Post/Redirect/Get pattern, for which you need to issue a GET [redirect](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/routing.html#redirect-helper).

Comment: I am trying to evaluate 'email' and 'pwd' attribute and unset them after having evaluated them, to avoid posting the form each time we refresh the page

Comment: HTTP is stateless. Removing data from one request does not affect a different request being sent in the future. You possibly want to implement the Post/Redirect/Get pattern, for which you need to issue a GET redirect.